# Translation of a weird email draft

Tags: translation

Today I have checked my drafts in GMAIL account just by chance, and I saw one email from 22.10.2021 (last friday) with chinese text and english subject. The subject makes sense since I am indeed learning some microservices stuff, but I have no idea how that got to my draft! Since I do not know if my email account is being hacked, only clue I have is this (supposedly) chinese text , but no translator was able to make any meaning from it - could you help? Maybe then I would find the source/website, although I do not remember visiting anything chinese...

this is the text

效敲椠⁳桴⁥楬歮琠⁯桴⁥楍牣獯牥楶散⁳潦⁲慊慶䐠癥汥灯牥⁳扥潯⁫桴瑡礠畯映畯摮椠瑮牥獥楴杮漠⁮敤敶潬数獲爮摥慨⹴潣⁭湡⁤慷瑮摥琠⁯浥楡⁬潴礠畯獲汥⹦栠瑴獰⼺搯癥汥灯牥⹳敲桤瑡挮浯瀯潲潭楴湯⽳業牣獯牥楶散⵳潦⵲慪慶搭癥汥灯牥⽳

[image: The email draft]

Comment: Just random Chinese characters, it doesn't make any sense.

Comment: It reminds me of those secret code used by spies to send encoded secret messages.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because mojibake does not strictly concern the Chinese language.

Comment: @WayneCheah So having disclosed the secret message, hocikto is now compromised! Hocikto, are you still alive?

Comment: "This question does not appear to be about Chinese language" :D how the hell am I supposed to know, this is all so alien to me that my best guess (and google translates' as well) is that this is chinese.

@TangHo thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is obviously glitched text, most likely caused by some encoding issue, like written in utf8 but parsed as another encoding for example.

Try switching the encoding of your browser might fix it.

Comment: Notice you're using non-english language, if your default encoding is something specific to your language, not unicode, then that might be the cause. Anyway, this has nothing to do with the chinese language.